# SFMC Query Activity Update records

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automationstudio

I have a query that uses an inner join.  The query will ultimately be used in an automation for a journey (to add new subscribers in daily, as they meet criteria).

The query works when I do a data 'overwrite', but does not yield any results when I attempt to 'update' or 'append'.

Here is the query:  using * in place of making this post too long.

`SELECT *
FROM 
[Deliverable_Users] Dusr
INNER JOIN ENT.[User_Team_Roles] UTR ON Dusr.Contact_Key = UTR.Contact_Key`

Comment: Just to make sure the basics are covered can you confirm if you see any error in the history?
If not, can you let us know if you have any primary key on the target data extension?
Doug

Comment: By George!  Errored out due to truncation.  Found something new.  The activity log.  Adjusted the field and we're back in business.

Comment: What does your target data extension look like? A bit hard to identify the problem without seeing the data extension you are trying to 'update' or 'append'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error Log showed it was a text field getting truncated.  Simple solution that I missed.